# Installed app, modifying html font/content/colors

Tags: shopify

I have added a plugin for social media login to my site. I am wondering where can i edit the html code to match the look and feel of my website? I could not locate it under the them code.

I could see the generated html within the page but cannot identify it anywhere in the them customization area.

ps: Shopify newbie.

Comment: What plugin and theme are you using?

Comment: it's a social login plugin (oxi social) and theme is expression. Generates a popup for login.I need to add some text elements/messaging to the popup. Theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If HTML generated by the plugin is rendered not in the `<iframe>`, just use you theme styles from the `assets` folder to override default CSS specified by plugin. Look for a filename `styles.scss.liquid` or `theme.scss.liquid` or similar.

If HTML is loaded within an iframe then go to the plugin settings and try to find where you can set custom CSS styles. Generally, plugins provide that option.

Comment: Checked and this loads from an iframe. Guess not a lot i could do about it. The customization provided by the plugin is very basic and i can't really edit contents. Alas!